# String#split behavior when splitting the empty string according the "\s+"

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am a newbie in Java. Unfortunately, in Java there is a lot of stuff that is very hard to understand to a newbie.

For example,

```
String str = "";
String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
System.out.println(arr.length);
System.exit(0);
```

The output is

```
[]
1
```

But why? I will appreciate if someone can explain me why the length of the array is 1.

Comment: `[]` is Java's confusing way to print the list `[""]` (the `"` are not printed)

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Java 8.

Comment: You have to learn to differ between the concepts of _literally nothing_ (what is in most cases the `null` value) or _empty value_ (what you find here as an empty string `""`, or in other instances as empty Lists,Collections,Arrays) where the surrounding type is there but it doesn't contain anything.

Comment: I would change UNFORTUNATELY to FORTUNATELY :) Otherwise, it would not be interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the implementation of [`Arrays.toString`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
public static String toString(Object[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(String.valueOf(a[i]));  // Let's print that!
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Now since the array is not empty, we'll get to the `for` loop.
We begin by appending `[` to the result. Then we append `String.valueOf(a[i])`. Let's try to print it:

```
String str = "";
String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(String.valueOf(arr[0]));
```

You'll see that the output is.. nothing! So the final result is:

```
[]
```

Please note that this has nothing to do with Java 8. The `split` method was introduced [much earlier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 10):

Even if the String instance is empty, it is still a String instance and the "nothing" must be put somewhere after `split()`. Thats the one element in the array.

If you printed `str[0]`, you would get an empty string. The real "nothing" would be `null` but than you would get `NullPointerException` (you can't call `split()` on null value)

Answer (score 7):

[image]Empty String is present at the Ist location of splitted array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "";
        String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

**Output**

```
[]

1
```